# timer jobs are showing "N/A" for their last run & schedule incremental search are not firing

Tags: central-administration, administration, timer-jobs, server-farm

I have SharePoint enterprise server 2013 with SP1, and i check my timer jobs and many of them are showing "N/A" beside their last run time, as follow:-

[image]

now i run the following command :-

```
Start-SPAdminJob -verbose
```

and i got the following :-

> VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Start-SPAdminJob.
>   Start-SPAdminJob : The administration service is running so all
>   administration jobs will be run in the timer service. At line:1 char:1
>   + Start-SPAdminJob -verbose
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...etStartAdminJob:    SPCmdletStartAdminJob)
>   [Start-SPAdminJob], SPException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletStartAdm    inJob
>
> VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Start-SPAdminJob. VERBOSE:
>   Leaving EndProcessing Method of Start-SPAdminJob.

so can anyone adivce what is causing this problem ? and even if i manually run the timer jobs i will keep receiving "N/A" for their last run time. I also checked the search schedule job and the search job will not get started . where i specify that the incremental search should run each 20 minutes. but the search will never start , only its "next incremental search" time will get updated ..

Comment: did you try to manually stope and start Timer Service and Admin services on all server in farm?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE i only have one server, and yes i manually restart the services but did not fix the problem... can you advice further please ?

Comment: try This 1) net stop SPAdminV4   2) 
 Start-SPAdminJob  3) 
 net start SPAdminV4

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE ok i run these 3 commands,, and i did not get any error. after that i went to one of the timer jobs and i run it manually,, i check the job again but still i get "N/A" beside its last run time...

Comment: that's weird.is it only one timer job or multiple? did you reboot the server so far? what happen if you run start-spadminjob -verbose

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE yes i did a full restart for the server, if i run the "start-spadminjob -verbose" i will get the result i showed in my original question , as follow:-.

Comment: VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Start-SPAdminJob. Start-SPAdminJob : The administration service is running so all administration jobs will be run in the timer service. At line:1 char:1 + Start-SPAdminJob -verbose + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...etStartAdminJob: SPCmdletStartAdminJob) [Start-SPAdminJob], SPException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletStartAdm inJob

    VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Start-SPAdminJob. VERBOSE: Leaving EndProcessing Method of Start-SPAdminJob.

Comment: is it prod or Staging? if non-prod...i would go and run the config wizard without any settings change.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE ok i will run the product configuration wizard and let you know,, thnaks